# How to insert a non standard row in a bound datagrid - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a wpf datagrid which is bound to a collection of data with the columns and bindings declared in xaml.

What I would like to do is have a first row that has allows the user to make mass changes to the rest of the column.

So for instance below the user could select a value in the top combo box, click the button and it would call an event handler that would change the underlying data and have the chance reflected in all the combo boxes in the column.

[image]

If adding a custom row is not possible I thought I could possibly create a space between the column headers and the rows and place the "first row" in the space created.

Please let me know if this is possible or if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the grid content template and have a stack panel with one grid for your custom row and another grid for all other rows and then might play around with their outlook to make them look as you want..

This is a very basic code for above said solution ----

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding list1}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ComboCol" Width="50">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox Text="Bind Your Combo Box" IsEditable="True"></ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding list2}" HeadersVisibility="Row">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Line1" Binding="{Binding Path=.}" Width="50"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Line2" Binding="{Binding Path=.}" Width="50"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <DataGrid/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Sounds promising, Could you please provide a bit more information?

Comment: added some code to give you an idea, you can set grid bindings to have it your way..

Comment: Ah ok I see what you mean. I'll give this a go. Can see potential complications with scrolling if I have 2 separate datagrids though.

Comment: added scrolling bit into it, this will make your grid scroll as one, also, you will find some issues regarding scroll event aggregation but am sure a simple search on SO will fix those issues.. good luck !